# Importar Google Fonts en CSS

Tags: css, google-fonts

Estoy tratando de importar 3 estilos distintos de fuentes desde Google Fonts en mi hoja de estilo de CSS y en la vista de la web no se reflejan.

Mi código en el CSS es este:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2? family = Coda + Título: wght @ 800 & display = swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2? family = Source + Sans + Pro: wght @ 700 & display = swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2? family = El + Messiri & display = swap');

body {
  background-color: cornsilk;
}

#contenedor {
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: o;
  margin-left: auto;
  font-family: "El Messiri", sans-serif;
}
header,
footer {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #e6fde2;
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;
}
title {
  font-family: "Coda Caption", sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: Cual es el HTML que usas?

Comment: Uso el html 5. O me preguntas el codigo?

Comment: Hola, Carla. Tienes que especificar dónde debería reflejarse. Si en todo el documento, título, etc.

Comment: lo aclare como font-family en  #contenedor   header,footer y title. A cada uno le asigne una de las fuentes q importe

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123393/discussion-between-jachguate-and-david-e-luna-m).

Answer (score 1):

Tienes varios errores

- Para comenzar, todos los espacios que hay en cada URL de la llamada a `https://fonts.googleapis.com`
- Puedo observar también que estás pasando un nombre de fuente como `Coda + Título` al API y luego la referencias como `Coda Caption` en el CSS. No traduzcas los parámetros, los API producen los resultados deseados si se les da la entrada precisa, y no suelen ser multi-idioma.

No voy a corregir cada uno de tus errores, mejor te enseño a pescar...

Comienza por lo básico, importa un font sin tantos parámetros:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Tangerine');
body {
    background-color: cornsilk;
}
h1 {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #E6FDE2;
    font-family: 'Tangerine', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<h1>Hola mundo</h1>
<p>¡El título se ve espectacular!</p>
```

A partir de allí, puedes ir agregándole complejidad, por ejemplo una fuente con un nombre compuesto:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dancing+Script');
body {
    background-color: cornsilk;
}
h1 {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #E6FDE2;
    font-family: 'Dancing Script', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<h1>Hola mundo</h1>
<p>¡El título se ve espectacular!</p>
```

Observa como la URL del `@import` no contiene ningún espacio... ahora agreguemos un segundo parámetro a la URL, por ejemplo, el parámetro `display`

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dancing+Script&display=swap');
body {
    background-color: cornsilk;
}
h1 {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #E6FDE2;
    font-family: 'Dancing Script', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<h1>Hola mundo</h1>
<p>¡El título se ve espectacular!</p>
```

Encontrarás la información que necesitas para agregar más parámetros en [Get Started with the Google Fonts API](https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/getting_started) (en inglés).

Un *tip* muy importante es que, si copias la URL que estás poniendo en un `@import` y la pegas en un navegador, el navegador te va a mostrar CSS válido, que es lo que devuelve el API, por ejemplo esta URL:

```
https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dancing+Script&display=swap
```

Ahora mismo devuelve lo siguiente:

```css
/* vietnamese */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Dancing Script';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-display: swap;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/dancingscript/v16/If2cXTr6YS-zF4S-kcSWSVi_sxjsohD9F50Ruu7BMSo3Rep8ltA.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0102-0103, U+0110-0111, U+0128-0129, U+0168-0169, U+01A0-01A1, U+01AF-01B0, U+1EA0-1EF9, U+20AB;
}
/* latin-ext */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Dancing Script';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-display: swap;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/dancingscript/v16/If2cXTr6YS-zF4S-kcSWSVi_sxjsohD9F50Ruu7BMSo3ROp8ltA.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0100-024F, U+0259, U+1E00-1EFF, U+2020, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2113, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;
}
/* latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Dancing Script';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-display: swap;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/dancingscript/v16/If2cXTr6YS-zF4S-kcSWSVi_sxjsohD9F50Ruu7BMSo3Sup8.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
}
```

Si la URL es inválida, por el contrario, te devolverá una página de error, de esa manera puedes estar segura de estar construyendo las URL's de manera correcta antes de ponerlas en tu hoja de estilo.

Comment: Yo copie tal cual estaba en Google Font, sin la etiqueta <style></style> porque iba a ponerla en mi hoja de CSS. 
Entonces debería sacar todos los espacios y así funcionaria?

Comment: No copiaste y pegaste... copiaste, pero copiaste mal. Puedes copiar y pegar o revisar caracter por caracter para asegurarte de tener exactamente lo mismo. Como he explicado en mi respuesta, tienes varios errores, los espacios son solo uno de ellos. Debes corregir las URL's siguiendo las reglas del API, que están documentadas Sigue. El último TIP que te dejé te ayudará a verificar si lo has hecho bien.

Comment: Por ejemplo, no existe la fuente `Coda+Título`, pero si `Coda+Caption`. No traduzcas nada de lo que está en parámetros... las API y los autómatas en general necesitan entradas precisas para dar los resultados esperados.

Comment: Creo que tengo el navegador con traducción automática, porque también me figura como familia de fuentes en lugar de font family. Voy a revisar eso y ver si me cambia el codigo. Gracias por hacérmelo notar

Comment: Igual, si _aprendes a pescar_, como ya he dicho, no necesitas copiar URL's, puedes construirlas tu misma si sabes el nombre de la fuente que quieres usar y los parámetros de como quieres obtenerla del API.

Comment: Bueno si confoirmado, el error base estaba en que tenia tradiccion automatica de las paginas en inlges :S
Gracias por hacerme notar de este pequeño detalle jeje. Voy a tratar de practicar lo q me enseñaste para ahorrarme estas complicaciones a futuro.

Comment: Me alegra ser de ayuda. Considera marcar la respuesta como aceptada, pues esto ayudará en el futuro a quienes lleguen aquí a identificar que la respuesta **si** fue de ayuda. Recuerda que en StackOverflow puedes saber, de esta manera, si hubo una respuesta útil y cuál es. Es muy útil cuando llegas aquí googlando un proximo problema. Esto no resta mérito a otras respuestas y en ocasiones habrá buenas o hasta mejores respuestas no aceptadas, pero si que ayuda. Si no sabes como aceptar una respuesta, haz el [tour].

Answer (score 0):

¡Hola! Lo mejor es que pongas el enlace del cdn de la fuente en el html o archivo donde tienes enlazada de la hoja de estilos.

Archivo html:

```
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lobster&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
```

style.css:

```
body {
  background-color: cornsilk;
}
#contenedor {
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: o;
  margin-left: auto;
  font-family: "El Messiri", sans-serif;
}
header,
footer {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #e6fde2;
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;
}
title {
  font-family: "Coda Caption", sans-serif;
}
```